# How do I modify a 3-D simulation grid to be 2-D?

Tags: simulations, coordinate-systems, plasma-physics

I am creating a particle in cell simulation that models an electron plasma in a cylindrical container. Part of this process is assigning charge density to grid points based on the position of each particle. My question is this: for the examples of these simulations that I have seen, the charge density is given by the amount of charge on a grid point divided by the volume of a unit cell, or: $\rho=\frac{q}{d\tau}$

which for cylindrical coordinates is: $\rho=\frac{q}{r\bigtriangleup_r \bigtriangleup_z \bigtriangleup_{\theta}}$, where the deltas represent the grid spacing that we have specified. For r and z, these are well defined.

however, we are taking the system to be symmetric about $\theta$, meaning that this simulation is basically in two dimensions, r and z, and that $\bigtriangleup_{\theta}=0$. How would I resolve this, because it looks to me like this would blow up?

Comment: I changed the title to be more descriptive; your question might get more views and answers this way. Feel free to roll back my edit (or re-edit it) if you feel this title doesn't describe your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take the charge distribution to be independent of $\theta$, and force the problem to be two-dimensional, you're not letting $\Delta_\theta \rightarrow 0$. You're actually letting $\Delta_\theta = 2\pi$.

If that's the only simulation you're going to run, the simplest solution is to set $\Delta_\theta = 2\pi$, and have your cells be rings at each value of $r$ and $z$. If you later want to allow $\theta$ dependence, you can then let $\Delta_\theta = 2\pi/n$, to allow for $n$ cells per $(r,z)$ ring.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in 2D space, then your charge density is really a charge *surface* density,
$$
\sigma=\frac{q}{dA}\equiv\frac{q}{\Delta r\Delta z},
$$
rather than a charge *volume* density.

Comment: That's what i thought at first, but to solve for the electric potential in this problem, I used Poisson's equation, which requires a volume charge density